# getting extension files from existing Magento for a new Magento website

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have two magento websites,

1) http://www.ooplo.com 
2) http://www.juggernet.com

the are a couple of extensions on ooplo i would like to copy to juggernet, however i haven't got the zip files anymore. I have tried copying the files from app, js, skin, media and includes from ooplo to juggernet whilst skipping the files that where identical to the two, however extensions such as xtento order tracking haven't imported.

I have disabled caching, re-indexed the site and deleted caching such in case.

Is the anyway of copying the exensions without the zip files, directly from the other magento site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the module xml files i.e. /etc/modules/SomeModule_Name.xml

Answer (score 0):

please check 
YOUR PROJECT NAME\downloader \ .cache\community

you can find all extension zip file